# Multi-language command-line source code formatter

Tags: code-formatting

Is there a command-line Unix tool that will format/indent/prettify source code in different languages? I'm especially interested in Java, JavaScript, PHP, and XML, but ideally it would handle others.

(I'm not looking for something to generate syntax-highlighting markup; I already know of a few tools that do that.)

Comment: I posted a similar question on askubuntu: [How to reformat/reindent all the source files in a given directory?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/98164/how-to-reformat-reindent-all-the-source-files-in-a-given-directory)

Comment: I haven't tried it myself but I think this is promising: https://github.com/google/google-java-format

Comment: various other options to do this [can be found here](https://alternativeto.net/software/artistic-style/)

Comment: and in the docs of [this atom beautifier](https://github.com/Glavin001/atom-beautify#beautifiers) which integrates with, and lists TONS of beautifiers, with a very versatile tool looking like [prettydiff](https://github.com/prettydiff/prettydiff)

Comment: and my final comment - i wrapped up a way to do this using Neovim, and [posted the answer here on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/a/1299926/38941)... but if you want to use vim, you might be able to get away with this one liner, `vim -s <(echo "gg=G\nZZ") YOUR_FILE_HERE`

Answer (score 5):

Artistic Style.
http://astyle.sourceforge.net/

Comment: which can be installed using homebrew on a mac, by running `brew install astyle`

Comment: and various other options to do this [can be found here](https://alternativeto.net/software/artistic-style/)

Answer (score 4):

I've always found Vim's code formatter a great option.  It is aware of many languages and can be reasonably customized.

You can pipe the relevant commands into vim like this:

```
vim MyClass.java <<< gg=G:wq
```

Explanation:

- `gg=G` formats the file
- `:wq` saves the file and returns to the command prompt

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work nicely when you have several java annotations before a method (e.g. `@Override`, `@Deprecated`)

Answer (score 3):

If you have set your auto-formatting options as project-specific settings in Eclipse, you can do something like:

```
/opt/local/eclipse/eclipse -nosplash
-application org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCodeFormatter
-verbose
-config .settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs
src/ tests/ doc/examples/
```

This means that you practically install and configure Eclipse for this purpose if only for using it's autoformatting features, regardless of what editor you use normally. :)

Source: http://blogs.operationaldynamics.com/andrew/software/java-gnome/eclipse-code-format-from-command-line

## Additional Notes

On Mac OS X:

```
/Applications/eclipse/java-oxygen/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse  -nosplash -application org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCodeFormatter -verbose -config ~/my-eclipse-workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs MyClass.java
```

Comment: Great tip. I hope you don't mind if I add the mac equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [`indent`](http://www.gnu.org/software/indent/) and  [`enscript`](http://www.gnu.org/software/enscript/).

Answer (score 0):

Vim generally has automatic syntax highlighting and is available on most Unix-based systems when you install. For formatting and indentation in Vim I use the `:set autoindent` and `:set tabstop=4` automatically when I start it. `autoindent` keeps the current indentation you are at when you start a new line, and `tabstop` sets how much your code is indented when you press tab (only for indentation, for tab in general use `shiftwidth`). To have these options configured whenever you start Vim put them in a `~/.vimrc` file.

Answer (score 0):

For XML and HTML I have used [htb](http://www.digital-mines.com/htb/).

If you are an Eclipse user then [JTidy](http://eclipsetidy.sourceforge.net/) is another option.

For Java there is [Jalopy](http://jalopy.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 0):

So, I bring to your attention Style Revisor, source code formatter with GUI and command-line interface. It will be support different languages, include JavaScript and PHP. If you're interested in command-line usage - you can define your own formatting style as addon. Of course, you can also use many predefined styles. Example:

```
./Style\ Revisor --lang=PHP --style=GNU --path=~/to-your-project-root-dir
```

Currently, Style Revisor supports two languages: C and Objective-C. Welcome: http://style-revisor.com/

Sincerely.

Comment: Indeed, I have been looking for this a long time. When it's ready for use, I will add vim-support via my autoformat plugin https://github.com/Chiel92/vim-autoformat. Too bad it's not open source.

Comment: Autoformat plugin for Vim? It's cool.